# Descartar elementos de una lista en Python

Tags: python, array, lista, numpy, matriz

tengo por un lado una lista A de 7 elementos, que contiene diferentes datos, y por otro lado otra lista B de 7 elementos, que contiene 0s y 1s. Lo que quiero es aplicar la lista B a la lista A de tal forma que, si por ejemplo B[2] vale 1, el dato en A[2] se mantiene, y si B[2] fuera 0, el dato de A[2] se eliminaría, de tal forma que si B = [1 1 1 1 0 1 1], el dato de A[5] se eliminaría y A sería una lista de 6 elementos.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). En este sitio no resolvemos tareas y/o proyectos. Para cada pregunta es necesario que agregues un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que podamos ayudarte. Por favor agrega el código que tienes hasta ahora aunque no funcione del todo.

Comment: `c = [a[i] for i in range(len(a)) if b[i]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con `numpy` puedes usar "*boolean indexing*" de esta forma:

```py
import numpy as np

A=np.array([1, 2, 3])
B=np.array([True, False, True])

print(A[B])
```

Si tienes escrito en `0` y `1`:

```py
import numpy as np

A=np.array([1, 2, 3])
B=np.array([1, 0, 1])

print(A[B==1])
```

Ambos dan como salida:

```
[1 3]
```